# Webscraping: output different to original data

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to webscrape a website displaying a countdown timer (the goal is to eventually make a discord bot that displays the remaining time left on the timer when requested). However when printing the data, the output is different from the original source.

Looking around, I couldn't find a solution to my problem. I'm sure im missing something, but clueless as to what it is (I'm only doing this as a personal project, very little previous experience with python)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result = requests.get("https://www.wowclassiccountdown.com/")
result.status_code
result.headers

c = result.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(c)

samples = soup.find_all("div", "fusion-digit")
samples[0]

data = {}
for div in samples:
    title = div.string.strip()
    data[title] = div.attrs['class']

    # displays data
    print(data)
```

I can't tell you what the expected output is as it's always changing, but it clearly should not be all 0. Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate it yourself. The target end datetime for the countdown is in the response from requests. You can grab current datetime and do the difference. I haven't added the hours, minutes to the following but that is easy from the secs

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

r = requests.get('https://www.wowclassiccountdown.com/')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
end = soup.select_one('#fusion-countdown-1')['data-timer']
ends = datetime.datetime.strptime(end, '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
start = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
starts = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
diff = ends - starts
diff
```

For me there is also a 9 hour time difference that needs accounting for.

Comment: Doing this still doesn't give me the exact same result, but I'm happy with it. It got more complicated when javascript was involved, wasn't counting on that so thanks

edit: whoops forgot to add the minutes, it works perfectly now haha

Answer (score 2):

The website that you are trying to **scrape** is using Javascript for the countdown *(try disabling Javascript in your web browser and you will see that the countdown will set itself to 0)*. Which sadly makes it impossible to **scrape** using the requests library.